# Failed to connect to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

I have attach my database file (.mdf) to my application. This file is in the folder bin\debug\database. But when I create setup file and install my app in other computers, I have some error when connecting to database, such as: "attemped to perform unauthorized operation", "access is denied" or "Database_log.mdf existed"... 
My app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
     <connectionStrings>
        <add name="XtopazConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database\XTOPAZ.mdf;Initial Catalog=XTOPAZ;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        </connectionStrings>
        <startup> 
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
        </startup>
</configuration>
```

My connection string and connecting function:

```
 public static void openConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Database\XTOPAZ.mdf"))
            {
                if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Database\XTOPAZ_log.ldf")) //delete current ldf file if it existed
                {
                    File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + @"\Database\XTOPAZ_log.ldf");
                }
                string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XtopazConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                //Set full permisstion access for database file
                DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + @"\Database\XTOPAZ.mdf");
                DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
                dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
                dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
                dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

                con.ConnectionString = s;
                con.Open();
            }
            else
            {
                Exception ex;
                ex = new Exception("Database file not found");
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured when trying to connect to database\r\nDetail: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

So how can I create my setup file and install application on others computer without any error?

Comment: post an image of your solution and show where the .mdf file sits.

Comment: Not sure why you try to delete the LDF file. Doesn't seems to be a correct move.

Comment: @Steve, I try to delete ldf file because I get an error "Database_log.mdf existed" when I open connection to database. I don't know why but when I delete it, this error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the application in administrator mode? 
Add a manifest file to the project Project -> Add New Item -> Application Manifest File. Then modify the requestedExecutionLevel to match this line:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: The first error disappears, but now there is other error: "Database.mdf existed". Should I attach database file one time or every time while loading my form ?